# CSP Setting in NUXT

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, content-security-policy

CSP blocking my local js files.
here my nuxt.config.js

```
      unsafeInlineCompatibility: true,
      policies: {
        'default-src': ["'self'", 'delivly.com', 'localhost', '*.gstatic.com', '*.fontawesome.com'],
        'script-src': ["'unsafe-inline'", 'delivly.com', 'localhost', '*.fontawesome.com', '*.googlesyndication.com', '*.googletagmanager.com'],
        'style-src': ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", 'delivly.com', '*.googleapis.com', '*.fontawesome.com'],
        'connect-src': ["'self'", 'wss://delivly.com']
      },
      addMeta: true
    }
```

Blocked files:

```
http://localhost:3010/_nuxt/runtime.js
http://localhost:3010/_nuxt/pages_index.js
http://localhost:3010/_nuxt/commons.app.js
http://localhost:3010/_nuxt/vendors.app.js
http://localhost:3010/_nuxt/app.js
```

Anyone know where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I understand it's too late to answer topicstarter, but may be it will come in handy for a "new generation".
The `localhost` acts as host-source, but host-sources allows the standard ports only.

On HTTP:-page the `localhost` will transform to `http://localhost` (Same origin Policy is used to restore scheme). For `http://` scheme standard port is 80, therefore any other ports will be forbidden by CSP (CSP3-browsers will allow port 443 too).

To allow any ports it need to use `*` as port number like that:
`'default-src': ['localhost:*']`
or to specify the real port number:
`'default-src': ['localhost:3010']`